# C code : cURL POST

Tags: c, post, curl, libcurl

I have some hard time with my code. I'm trying to connect to a website using cURL.
Let's see the code of the website :

```
<td class="input "><input tabindex="1" class="text" name="authentificationLogin" id="authentificationLogin" type="text"/></td>
<td class="input "><input tabindex="2" class="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="authentificationPassword" id="authentificationPassword" type="password"/></td>
<td class="input "><input name="authentificationRedirection" id="authentificationRedirection" type="hidden" value="http://myWebsite/?Redirect"/><input name="authentification08e11696a1" id="authentification08e11696a1" type="hidden" value=""/><br/><button class="button button-style" type="submit" name="Submit" id="authentificationSubmit" onclick="return lock(&quot;id:authentificationSubmit&quot;);">
```

Now, let's see my code :

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

void Demarrage(void){
    CURLcode res;
    const char *userAgentMozilla = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.8.1.20) Gecko/20081217 Firefox/2.0.0.20";     // set userAgent
    const char *data = "&to=gaia&login=myName&password=myPassword&isBoxStyle=";     // set the data to send
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *handle;
    handle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,1);       // clean up session.
    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,userAgentMozilla);        // set the user agent
    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_URL,"http://myWebsite.com/logIn");     // set the url
    curl_easy_perform(handle);                              // perform
                                                            // I must to take cookies that the website gave to me.
    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,58L);     // size of the request.
    curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,data);       // aray of the POST request
    curl_easy_perform(handle);                              // perform and connect to the Website

}
```

I also use Wireshark,

What i have when i do it manually ( that's printable caract only )

```
$QU9Eq@*Y!P9?PDpPOST /site/doLogIn HTTP/1.1
```

I don't know what it is.

```
Host: myWebsite.com
```

The host.

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 140
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
```

Some formalities I think.

```
Origin: http://myWebsite.com
```

Host again. with type.

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I don't know what it is.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36
```

User Agent. I don't really understand why there is 4 types of user agent.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://myWebsite/logIn
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Formalities.

```
Cookie: advertisementcookie=1; __utma=108225430.1356423961.1414526372.1414789248.1414921274.6; __utmz=108225430.1414526372.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); sessionprod=oekotlo6tfbujtpfirddvvqlp1; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1356423961.1414526372
```

Well, that start to be interessant. This is cookies sent to the website during the HTTP request. They changed each time I sent a new HTTP request.

```
&to=gaia&login=myName&password=myPassword&redirection=http%3A%2F%2FmyWebsite.com%2%2F%3Fidentification%3D1&isBoxStyle=&08e11696a1=
```

This is the principal of my request. Name and password are sent to the server.

I have no error but my code is not working because my hour of last connection isn't change... Probably because i don't set cookies.
I'm really inexperienced and I know I'm doing probably so many stupid error. But, please, if you have any informations, answer to my question...
Have you some genious ideas for repair this code ?

Best regards.
Xavier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the string "&to=gaia&login=myName&password=myPassword&redirection=http%3A%" ... to the [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) option for such a "regular" POST.

The [CURLOPT_HTTPPOST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html) option that you use (in combination with curl_formadd etc) is for multipart formposts, which you obviously don't want!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried during hours and hours, without sucess. But i'm still not connect.
I send exactly the same packet that the one i have when i connect manually with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. I can see him with Wireshark but, and i don't know why, i'm still not connect ...

Comment: Well, that is how you make the request as per your question. You might also need to mimic browsers in more aspects to have the site accept your post, where using cookies is one important part. Still not what you asked for...

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel. But I have hard time with all of that. I'm starting with your librairies ( who seems to be really powerfull !! ). I edited my main post. I think ( and I hop ) I did the right choice to mimic browsers but i have any ideas for cookies.

Comment: After 5 days, the problem stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to told you that i finally did it.
Thanks Daniel for your library and example on your website :

```
char *data = &togaia&login=login&password=pswd&isBoxStyle=
const char *userAgentMozilla = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
CURLcode res;
CURLcode err;

curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,1);       // clean up session.
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");  // save cookie. use it for each action on a website when you are register, juste doing curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,userAgentMozilla);        // set the user agent
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_URL,"http://thewebsite/site/doLogIn");     // set the url                         // perform
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,strlen(data));     // size of the request.
curl_easy_setopt(handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,data);       // aray of the POST request
res = curl_easy_perform(handle);                              // perform and connect to the Website
```

If you have probleme, do no hesitate to post, and i will try to help you :)
It is the answer to connect to the website, you can also look what i sniffed to have an example ;)